# setsockopt fails for IPPROTO_TCP IP_TOS in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

My code fails. I am running as root (same behavior as normal user)

First I want to set the TOS and then get the value.

```
int tos_local = 0x28;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, IP_TOS,  &tos_local, sizeof(tos_local))) {
    error("error at socket option");
} else {
    int tos=0;
    int toslen=0;

    if (getsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, IP_TOS,  &tos, &toslen) < 0) {
            error("error to get option");
    }else {
            printf ("changing tos opt = %d\n",tos);
    }
}
```

the printf prints

> changing tos opt = 0

I would expect to print 0x28 (40).

What is the problem?

The correct answer:

```
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, **IPPROTO_IP**, IP_TOS,  &tos_local, sizeof(tos_local))) {

    int tos=0;
    int toslen=sizeof(tos); //that line here

    if (getsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS,  &tos, &toslen) < 0) {
```

Comment: The 5th argument of getsockopt is the size of the buffer pointed to by the 4th arg. So you need to delete the & in your example code. Or better yet, put sizeof(tos) there, like Seth said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IP_TOS` has level `IPPROTO_IP`, not `IPPROTO_TCP`.

See [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip).

This affects both setting and getting the option.

Also, what Seth said about initializing the length parameter, which affects only `getsockopt`.

Comment: Indeed.  And IP_TOS happens to equal 1, as does TCP_NODELAY, so this code actually does something... Just not what was intended.

Comment: @Nemo: Yeah, they should have designed these as bitfields instead of separate parameters.  But that's water under the bridge.

Answer (score 3):

When calling getsockopt, you pass in the size of the memory pointed to by &tos.   In other words initialize toslen to sizeof(tos).

Comment: I get compiler warning error: warning: passing argument 5 of getsockopt makes pointer from integer without a cast when I pass sizeof(tos). Additionally the getsockoption fails with "Bad Address"

Comment: @cateof: passing `&tos_len` as the parameter is correct, but you need to declare it as `int tos_len = sizeof (tos);` and not `0`.

Comment: @cateof: @Ben Voight: I think you mean, passing &tos_len as the parameter is correct, but you need to initialize it to sizeof(tos) and not 0.